# NiceMatrix and alignment of cells

Tags: alignment, nicematrix

I am building a table in a `NiceTabularX` environment, and I have a small alignment issue. In one of my rows, I would like to have the content rotated by 90° (direct), centered horizontally and bottom-aligned vertically. However, if I use `X[l,m]` columns, the vertical alignment is perfect but I don't get the horizontally-centered alignment correct, and if I use `X[c,m]` I get the correct horizontally-centered alignment, but the vertical bottom alignment goes away. Using c type columns would bring the correct alignment on both sides, but then it's a nightmare to calculate the size of the columns to make sure my table has the right width in total (which is precisely why I use `NiceTabularX` and not `NiceTabular`).

Here is a simplified example that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

With \verb!X[l]! style columns, I get the correct vertical alignment to the bottom of the row, but the elements are not horizontally centered:

\def\arraystretch{1}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{9cm}{X[l]X[l]X[l]X[l]}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate}
    \textmd{Short} & \textmd{Verylong} & \textmd{T} & \textmd{Medium} \\
     & F & G & H \\
    I & J & \Block{1-2}{KL} & \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\vspace{5mm}

With \verb!X[c]! style columns, I get the correct vertical alignment to the bottom of the row, but the elements are not horizontally centered anymore:

\def\arraystretch{1}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{9cm}{X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate}
    \textmd{Short} & \textmd{Verylong} & \textmd{T} & \textmd{Medium} \\
     & F & G & H \\
    I & J & \Block{1-2}{KL} & \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\vspace{5mm}

With \verb!c! style columns, I get the right result in terms of alignments, but unfortunately I really have to work with the \verb!NiceTabularX! environment to get the total width of my table correct:

\def\arraystretch{1}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{9cm}{cccc}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate}
    \textmd{Short} & \textmd{Verylong} & \textmd{T} & \textmd{Medium} \\
     & F & G & H \\
    I & J & \Block{1-2}{KL} & \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}
    
\end{document}
```

If you have any idea how to make this work, I would be very grateful!

Have an excellent day,

Simon

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{9cm}{*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\rotate\raggedright\arraybackslash}
    \textmd{Short} & \textmd{Verylong} & \textmd{T} & \textmd{Medium} \\
    & F & G & H \\
    I & J & \Block{1-2}{KL} & \\
    M & N & O & P\\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a million, it works perfectly well! I have to admit I would never have thought about putting \raggedright for that...